Faster alternative to starting wmic as subprocess to collect data in Python?
I have written a program that pulls various data pieces from whatever machine it is running on, and I'm having some trouble with a particular query I built into it. This one line is [correctly] querying the installed products on the machine, but it takes roughly 10-15 seconds to run. Is there a better way to write this line? The goal is to simply gather the names...which it does...slowly.
wmicData=subprocess.check_output(['wmic','product','get','name'])

It does the job, I'm just not sure how to make it faster...if that's even possible with Python alone.

In general, doing it faster will mean not using subprocess but looking for a native API that achieves the same purpose. I'd probably start by searching through the documentation for pywin32, and/or Microsoft's documentation to figure out how to get the information you want in C. Once you know the C call, you can find preexisting wrappers in Python or build your own (as with ctypes).

Here are a couple of examples of getting installed software using Python
import wmi
import win32api
import win32con

# Version 1 WMI
c = wmi.WMI()
for s in c.query('SELECT * from Win32_Product'):
    print(s.Name)

# Version 2 Registry
index = 0
key = win32api.RegOpenKey(win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall')
while True:
    subkeyname = win32api.RegEnumKey(key, index)
    index += 1
    subkey = win32api.RegOpenKey(key, subkeyname)
    try:
        val = win32api.RegQueryValueEx(subkey, 'DisplayName')
        if val[0]:
            print(val[0])
    except:
        pass

I will leave it to you to do proper error handling, choose the properties values you want etc
For the registry version, you would have to repeat with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall for 32-bit installers and possibly HKEY_CURRENT_USER variants for user level installs.
